# to combine the output of three rows in to single value in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

By using the below query the output is displayed as below

```
SELECT dlr_acc_acct_id , (   NVL (dlr_jan, 'D')
               || NVL (dlr_feb, 'D')
               || NVL (dlr_mar, 'D')
               || NVL (dlr_apr, 'D')
               || NVL (dlr_may, 'D')
               || NVL (dlr_jun, 'D')
               || NVL (dlr_jul, 'D')
               || NVL (dlr_aug, 'D')
               || NVL (dlr_sep, 'D')
               || NVL (dlr_oct, 'D')
               || NVL (dlr_nov, 'D')
               || NVL (dlr_dec, 'D')
              ) payment_history_profile
               FROM daybreak.accounts acc, daybreak.delinquency_ratings dr
 WHERE  dlr_acc_acct_id = acc.ACC_ACCT_ID 
 and dlr_acc_acct_id= '20090305975688'
 and dlr_year in (2011,2010,2009)
```

the output is

```
DLR_ACC_ACCT_ID,PAYMENT_HISTORY_PROFILE
20090305975688,DD0000000000
20090305975688,000000000000
20090305975688,0000000DDDDD
```

My expected output is

```
dlr_acc_acct_id payment_history_profile
20090305975688  DD00000000000000000000000000000DDDDD
```

Comment: Try using `listagg` -- that should combine the rows into a single row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on 11gR2 and above, use **LISTAGG**:

```
SELECT DLR_ACC_ACCT_ID,
  listagg(PAYMENT_HISTORY_PROFILE, '') within GROUP(
ORDER BY PAYMENT_HISTORY_PROFILE) PAYMENT_HISTORY_PROFILE
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY DLR_ACC_ACCT_ID;
```

Use appropriate column in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need aggregation if you want only one row:

```
SELECT dlr_acc_acct_id,
       (NVL(MAX(dlr_jan), 'D')
               || NVL(MAX(dlr_feb), 'D')
               || NVL(MAX(dlr_mar), 'D')
               || NVL(MAX(dlr_apr), 'D')
               || NVL(MAX(dlr_may), 'D')
               || NVL(MAX(dlr_jun), 'D')
               || NVL(MAX(dlr_jul), 'D')
               || NVL(MAX(dlr_aug), 'D')
               || NVL(MAX(dlr_sep), 'D')
               || NVL(MAX(dlr_oct), 'D')
               || NVL(MAX(dlr_nov), 'D')
               || NVL(MAX(dlr_dec), 'D')
              ) payment_history_profile
FROM daybreak.accounts acc JOIN
     daybreak.delinquency_ratings dr
     ON  dlr_acc_acct_id = acc.ACC_ACCT_ID 
WHERE dlr_acc_acct_id = '20090305975688'
GROUP BY dlr_acc_acct_id;
```

Also, learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: let me be more specific.

Comment: select * from delinquency_ratings  where dlr_acc_acct_id = '20090305975688' and dlr_year in (2009,2010,2011)  DLR_ACC_ACCT_ID DLR_YEAR DLR_JAN DLR_FEB DLR_MAR DLR_APR DLR_MAY DLR_JUN DLR_JUL DLR_AUG DLR_SEP DLR_OCT DLR_NOV DLR_DEC DLR_RATING_TYPE
20090305975688 2,009   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 C
20090305975688 2,010 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 C
20090305975688 2,011 0 0 0 0 0 0 0      C
I want all the columns  data dlr_jan to dlr_dec starting from 2011 to 2009 in a single value

Answer (score 0):

Pushing what you have down into a subquery and adding the year for ordering listagg(), the following should work:

```
SELECT dlr_acc_acct_id
      , listagg(payment_history_profile,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY dlr_year) as full_history_profile
FROM (
SELECT dlr_acc_acct_id 
      ,dlr_year
      , (   NVL (dlr_jan, 'D')
               || NVL (dlr_feb, 'D')
               || NVL (dlr_mar, 'D')
               || NVL (dlr_apr, 'D')
               || NVL (dlr_may, 'D')
               || NVL (dlr_jun, 'D')
               || NVL (dlr_jul, 'D')
               || NVL (dlr_aug, 'D')
               || NVL (dlr_sep, 'D')
               || NVL (dlr_oct, 'D')
               || NVL (dlr_nov, 'D')
               || NVL (dlr_dec, 'D')
              ) payment_history_profile
FROM daybreak.accounts acc, daybreak.delinquency_ratings dr
 WHERE  dlr_acc_acct_id = acc.ACC_ACCT_ID 
 and dlr_acc_acct_id= '20090305975688'
 and dlr_year in (2011,2010,2009) )
 GROUP BY dlr_acc_acct_id
```